# Python regular expressions return true/false

Tags: python, regex

Using Python regular expressions how can you get a `True`/`False` returned? All Python returns is:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at ...>
```

Comment: try `bool(re.search(pattern=META_VAR_REGEX, string=coq_str))`.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

`Match` objects are always true, and `None` is returned if there is no match. Just test for trueness.

```
if re.match(...):
```

Comment: re.match(...) would return true if the string's beginning part match the regular pattern. While search will confirm the pattern anywhere in the string.

Comment: It may be more desirable to use ``if re.match(...) is None:`` instead

Comment: sorry, did you address the comments in your answer? Its unclear to me, do you mind clarifying?

Comment: May I ask _why_ `re` is designed like this? If `match` objects are always true, why doesn't it just return `True` at the first place, given that we always need to know whether the answer is true or false anyway?

Comment: @ytu: Because then you can do [everything else you need to](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

Comment: Note that `<_sre.SRE_Match... == True` and `<_sre.SRE_Match... == False` are both `False`, so you may wish to cast the result to a `bool` in some cases.

Comment: @NuclearPeon `re.match` will never return `False`, so is that actually useful? Or is it to cover situations where you're not sure what value might be passed in?

Comment: Why not just convert to bool `if bool(re.match(...)):`

Answer (score 255):

If you really need `True` or `False`, just use `bool`

```
>>> bool(re.search("hi", "abcdefghijkl"))
True
>>> bool(re.search("hi", "abcdefgijkl"))
False
```

As other answers have pointed out, if you are just using it as a condition for an `if` or `while`, you can use it directly without wrapping in `bool()`

Comment: `bool` value is needed when the conditional statement contains boolean arithmetic operation. eg: if (re.search("a","abc") & True):

Comment: @AizzatSuhardi, `&` is a **bitwise** operaration. `and` would be the **boolean** operation.

Comment: thanks @JohnLaRooy. correction: `(re.search("a","abc") and True)`

Comment: how is this different from ignacio's answer?

Comment: Wrapping in `bool` makes the intention of the programmer clear to the reader.

Comment: This is not just clearer, in some cases necessary i.e. if you are using the assertTrue function in python unit test to check a regex match (you need a boolean value, not expression). Or any function where you need a boolean input...

Answer (score 15):

Here is my method:

```
import re
# Compile
p = re.compile(r'hi')
# Match and print
print bool(p.match("abcdefghijkl"))
```

Comment: p = re.comp**il**e(r'hi')  :-P

Comment: yeah and it returns "False"

Comment: if you change `match` to `search`, it'll return True

Answer (score 12):

Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams is correct. But to elaborate, `re.match()` will return either `None`, which evaluates to `False`, or a match object, which will always be `True` as he said. Only if you want information about the part(s) that matched your regular expression do you need to check out the contents of the match object.

Answer (score 9):

One way to do this is just to test against the return value. Because you're getting `<_sre.SRE_Match object at ...>` it means that this will evaluate to true. When the regular expression isn't matched you'll the return value None, which evaluates to false.

```
import re

if re.search("c", "abcdef"):
    print "hi"
```

Produces `hi` as output.

Comment: You *always* get a return value; `None` is the default if nothing is explicitly returned.

Comment: Thanks -- corrected that. I was just going by what I saw in the REPL.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `re.match()` or `re.search()`.
Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is what Perl does by default). refer [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)