# Why the code not working need to return True or False from the string if regex matches with condition

Tags: python, regex

I wrote one program to find the matches. its working fine. If the string is not proper it has to return false. example if my `string_` contains 2 commas or instead of `reject` or `any` if some other string came it has to return `false`. My string only expect string as `reject` or `any`

```
import re
string_ = '''192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2/32,192.168.1.5-192.168.1.7,reject,any,
reject,192.168.1.1/32,reject,any,
172.168.1.4-172.168.1.4,reject'''
result = re.findall('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/?\d{0,}|[any|reject]+', string_)
#print(result)
if result :
    print (True)
```

Expecting false for the string below

```
     test = '''192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2/32,192.168.1.5-192.168.1.7,reject,any,ip_address
reject,192.168.1.1/32,reject,any,
172.168.1.4-172.168.1.4,reject'''
bool(re.search('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/?\d{0,}|[any|reject]+', test))
```

Expected Out is `False`, My Out is `True`

```
test1 = '''192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2/32,192.168.1.5-192.168.1.7,reject,any,,,,
    reject,192.168.1.1/32,reject,any,
    172.168.1.4-172.168.1.4,reject'''
bool(re.search('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/?\d{0,}|[any|reject]+', test1))
```

Expected Out is `False`, My Out is `True`

Expected Out

`False`

Its not duplicate of [Python regular expressions return true/false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576962/python-regular-expressions-return-true-false)

Comment: Why do you want it returns false? `search` returns true if it matches, and here, it matches at least the first IP address. Use `^(?:(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?:/\d+)?|(?:any|reject)),?)+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc [search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=search#re.search)

> re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding match object. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

Your regex is matching the first IP, then it returns True.

If you want the whole string contains only IP or any or reject, you have to anchor your regex, this one does the job:

```
^(?:(?:-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?:/\d+)?|\b(?:any|reject)\b),?)+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  (?:               # start non capture group
    (?:             # start non capture group
      (?:           # start non capture group
        (?<=\d)     # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a digit before
        -           # an hyphen
      )?            # end group, optional
      \d{1,3}       # 1 up to 3 digits
      (?:           # start non capture group
        \.          # a dot
        \d{1,3}     # 1 up to 3 digits
      ){3}          # end group, must appear 3 times
      (?:           # start non capture group
        /           # a slash
        \d+         # 1 or more digits
      )?            # end group, optional
     |              # OR
      \b            # word boundary
      (?:           # start non capture group
        any         # literally  "any"
       |            # OR
        reject      # literally  "reject"
      )             # end goup
      \b            # word boundary
    )               # end group
    ,?              # optional comma
  )+                # end group, may appear 1 or more times
$                   # end of line
```

**code:**

```
import re

test1 = '''192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2/32,192.168.1.5-192.168.1.7,reject,any,,,,
    reject,192.168.1.1/32,reject,any,
    172.168.1.4-172.168.1.4,reject'''
res = bool(re.search(r'^(?:(?:(?:(?<=\d)-)?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?:/\d+)?|\b(?:any|reject)\b),?)+$', test1))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
False
```

Comment: Can you show us the result for a valid string ? Your regex does not include "-" and you can also have "anyany" return True. Also you're not taking into account the multilines part of the string.

Comment: @naurel: Good catch, fixed.

Comment: almost ! "any-any" will return True. The "-" can only be between 2 IPs without mask if I'm correct. Note that it was not specified by cdac

Comment: You can shorten your pattern a little replacing `|\b(?:any|reject)\b),?)+$` with `|any|reject)\b,?)+$`